# Using kint in views-view-unformatted

Tags: 8, debugging

What is corect way to use kint in  views-view-unformatted.html.twig

I do:

```
{{ kint(rows) }}
```

but I get this error.

Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20794259 bytes) in /home/inatcent/public_html/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Render/Renderer.php on line 448

And for **{{ kint(row) }}** I get null what is ok. But I want more staff. :)

Comment: `Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted` you need to increase your php memory_limit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Option 1: Try to increase your php memory limit above the 250 MB.

Option 2: Don't try to debug all the rows at once.

```
{{ for row in rows }}
  {{ kint(row) }}
{{ endfor }}
```

P.S.

The reason `{{ row }}` was null, was because that variable does not exist in the template unless declared like in my example above.